# Notify multiple email addresses on comments

Tags: plugin-recommendation, comments, email

Can you recommend a plugin that enables notification on multiple email addresses on posted comments? Looking for a plugin that both notifies a global list of email addresses and the author of the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Post authors are notified of new comments by default; there are several plugins that modify this behavior. See [`wp_notify_postauthor`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_notify_postauthor).

You can hook into [`comment_notification_recipients`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comment_notification_recipients/) and add an aribtrary list of recipients as described [here](https://cgd.io/2014/change-wordpress-comment-notification-email-recipient-conditionally/). Then you could create a metabox or dashboard widget to manage the recipient list.

Keep in mind that this functionality might be abused as a spam engine or turned into one unintentionally if your comment spam filtering is inadequate.

Answer (score 2):

Use this plugin: comment notifier

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/comments-notifier/

Comment: That plugin hasn't been updated in 2 years. We need something new.

Answer (score 1):

Since that could lead to a whole bunch of e-mails being sent out to a whole lot of people I think what you are aiming at is that one of the persons that receives the e-mail needs to answer on a comment.

For that purpose the following is maybe a better idea: install http://osticket.com and set up a support@yoursite e-mail adres for incoming new tickets. Then create staff members for each of the persons that would need to get that information on a new comment.

Now, when a comment is placed, a new ticket is created in the open queue. And can then be assigned to one of the members to process further. The "open queue" shows the tickets that noone has picked up yet and the "assigned" the ones that have been assigned.

Probably a lot more use cases can then be handled.

You can set it up in 20 minutes.

Comment: Very interesting approach! However, as bit of a overkill for my need. I only need to notify authors and a couple of admins.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the Subscribe to Comments Reloaded plugin ? http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/subscribe-to-comments-reloaded/

After seeing your comment, it's probably easiest to set up an admin email account which forwards to all admins (if you just want comment notifications, you can easily filter the forwarding rule).

Comment: Great plugi, but it's not really what I'm looking for. I'm only looking on notifying the author and all admins on the page...not the users.

Comment: Ah ok - probably easiest to use a generic gmail account and forward to the admins - don't think there's a plugin that does what you need.